# Vue - Proper way to modify slots before rendering - Goal: add transition group key programatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a wrapper component that is just a `<transition-group>` component accepting content via its default slot.  The content passed through the default slot is a series of secondary vue components.

Since items in a transition group need to be keyed, how would I go about adding the key to the slot items?  As they are slotted and not rendered in a v-for loop, I think the keys would need to be added programmatically.

Below is a snippet to play with.  You'll see my approach in the created() hook, which seems to work on initial page load/rendering, however when hot-reload refreshes in my dev environment, the keys are lost and the error about transition group children needing keys comes back.

Is there a better approach to accomplish this that would keep hot-reload happy?  Perhaps I shouldn't worry about hot-reload since it's only a development feature, but my thinking is that if hot-reload is not liking my approach, then I may be doing it incorrectly and there is probably a better way.

Thoughts?

I'm also just curious in general about when in the lifecycle is the right time to make modifications to the slot nodes.  And further, is the node.key the right place to apply the unique key?  Which property in the slot node is the right property to edit? (i.e. there is also a 'key' set in the component data property, when the key is set in a v-for loop)

Thanks so much for any insight you can offer!

```js
Vue.component('wrapper-component', {
  render(h) {
    return h('transition-group', this.$slots.default)
  },
  
  // my attempt at providing a unique key for transition children is in created() hook below
  // this works on itital page load/rendering - but breaks when hot-reload refreshes my development site
  // uncomment created() hook to see my approach in action - works here on page reload, but does not hold up with hot-reload (i.e. once hot-reload refreshes, the transition items no longer have their unique keys)
  
/*  
  created() {
    this.$slots.default = this.$slots.default.map((node, index) => {
      node.key = `${node.tag}-${index}`
      return node
    })
  }
*/
  
});

Vue.component('child-item', {
  render(h) {
    return h('div', this.$slots.default)
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
});
```

```css
div {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <wrapper-component>
    <child-item>My Child 1</child-item>
    <child-item>My Child 2</child-item>
    <child-item>My Child 3</child-item>
    <child-item>My Child 4</child-item>
  </wrapper-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add `beforeUpdate` hook:

```
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.$slots.default = this.$slots.default.map((node, index) => {
      node.key = `${node.tag}-${index}`
      return node
    })
  }
```

Comment: I guess it was that simple.  I'll need to do some more testing to know for sure, and the logic is needed in the created() and beforeUpdate() hooks, but it's looking good so far! 

Seems like editing the node.key is working, so I guess I'll just trust that this is a good way to accomplish what I need.  Funny how my mind expects things to be complicated and they're not!  Thanks so much for your insight!